# Refresh ViewPager's fragments on swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to use a viewpager to display information from a stack of objects. 
I have a viewpager with 4 fragments and I want that every time I swipe the viewpager to another fragment the non visible fragments pop/peek an object from the stack.

I already tried some stuff. I was trying to listen to page changes using `OnPageChangeListener()`and find some way to update the fragment content from inside the activity. I didn't manage to do that.

Here is my adapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter_Browse extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

FragmentManager mManager;

public PagerAdapter_Browse(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mManager = fm;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            return new FragmentBrowseOne();
        case 1:
            return new FragmentBrowseTwo();
        case 2:
            return new FragmentBrowseThree();
        case 3:
            return new FragmentBrowseFour();
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}
}
```

One of my fragments (all look more a less the same):

```
public class FragmentBrowseOne extends Fragment {


ImageView main_img;
View view;

public FragmentBrowseOne(){
    setArguments(new Bundle());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    BitmapDrawable profilePic;

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_browse_one, container, false);

    main_img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_img);

    Bitmap temp = bundle.getParcelable("object");
    profilePic = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), temp);
    main_img.setBackground(profilePic);

    main_img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    return view;
}
}
```

And here is part of my activity:

```
    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_browser);
    padapter = new PagerAdapter_Browse(getSupportFragmentManager());

    PagerAdapter wrappedAdapter = new InfinitePagerAdapter(padapter);
    viewpager.setAdapter(wrappedAdapter);

    viewpager.setId(R.id.pager);

    viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

    viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }

        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            FragmentBrowseOne fragment = new FragmentBrowseOne();

            Bitmap pic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.samplegirl4);
            fragment.getArguments().putParcelable("object", pic);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Yes, I debugged it. The problem is not with the code itself. It's a conceptual problem. I want to find a way to refresh all the fragments but the current fragment. Inside `onPageSelected()` I already receive the position of the fragment that I don't want to refresh (since it's visible) correctly, however I can't find a way to update the other fragments inside this method.

Comment: You can write a `refresh()` method in each fragment and then call it using adapter. When you get the position of currently selected fragment, there call the `refresh()` method of your other 3 fragments.

Comment: Actually your question is little confusing. It's unclear that if you are asking about how to get the other 3 fragment to refresh OR how to refresh the content of the fragment? Please edit it with clear words.

Answer (score 1):

Use SetArguments and pass it in bundle for every fragment. Arguments must contain new object in which required changes are made. 
Use constructor

```
public FragmentNumber(){
        setArguments(new Bundle());
}
```

Return Fragment by using below method

```
FragmentNumber fragment = new FragmentNumber();
  fragment.getArguments().putSerializable("object", newobject);
```

This will refresh data inside fragment whenever page changed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to be a good approach. How can I retrieve the "object" inside the fragment in order to update the content of my views?

Comment: In on create view get Bundle bundle = getarguments(); and extract the objects passed and set the views.

Comment: Yes, I did that already but I still get null element from the bundle `getArguments()`. Also I was debugging and when I make  `FragmentNumber fragment = new FragmentNumber();` it goes over the constructor, however `onCreateView()` doesn't seem to be executed.

Comment: Could post your pageradapter code and fragment code here. I can have more understanding.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question since I can't post that amount of code here in comments. You can check it out now. Thanks.

Comment: to be sure, have you used this "fragment.getArguments().putSerializable("object", newobject);" and returning fragment in PagerAdapter_Browse class.

Comment: I used `fragment.getArguments().putParcelable("object", pic);` since I'm passing a bitmap. I believe the result is the same because inside the fragment's `onCreateView()` I'm using `Bitmap temp = bundle.getParcelable("object");`. 
What do you mean by returning fragment in PagerAdapter_Browse class? I didn't chage anything in the adapter class, maybe that's the problem. What I'm I supposed to do there?

Comment: Instead of returning new Fragment in getItem() return Fragment object with new bundle.

Comment: Yes I got it now. But won't this only refresh the fragment that is by standard refreshed by the adapter? I mean, by default when I change page there is one fragment that is refreshed by calling the `getItem()`method. With your solution, I think you just enable the option to refresh that same fragment with custom data, right?